# upload file to server using ionic framework and web api

Tags: ionic-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to upload video file to the remote server using ionic framework capacitor and webApi. But when run the code, it is showing the error like **Invalid 'HttpContent' instance provided. It does not have a content type header starting with 'multipart/'. Parameter name: content with ionic**.

My Code:
MyController.cs(webApi):

```
[Route("api/Upload")]
public async Task<string> Upload()
{
    try
    {
        var fileuploadPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileUploadLocation"];
        var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(fileuploadPath);
        var content = new StreamContent(HttpContext.Current.Request.GetBufferlessInputStream(true));
        foreach (var header in Request.Content.Headers)
        {
            content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value);
        }
        await content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
        string uploadingFileName = provider.FileData.Select(x => x.LocalFileName).FirstOrDefault();
        string originalFileName = String.Concat(fileuploadPath, "\\" + (provider.Contents[0].Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName).Trim(new Char[] { '"' }));
        if (File.Exists(originalFileName))
        {
            File.Delete(originalFileName);
        }
        File.Move(uploadingFileName, originalFileName);

        return "success";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }

        }
```

webconfig.cs:

```
<add key="FileUploadLocation" value="D:\Asp.Net\Fileupload" />
```

upload.html:

```
<input #fileInput type="file" [multiple]="true"  (change)="uploadFiles( fileInput.files ); fileInput.value = null;"/>
```

upload.ts:

```
public async uploadFiles( files: File[] ) : Promise<void> 
{
    Array.from(files).forEach(async(file1:any)=>
    {
        try
        {
          this.uploads.push(await this.Service.uploadFile(file1)); 
        }
        catch ( error ) 
        {
           console.warn( "File upload failed." );
           console.error( error );
        }
    });
}
```

service.ts:

```
public async uploadFile( file: File ) : Promise<UploadResult> 
{
    var result = await this.httpClient.post<ApiUploadResult>("http://12.99.45.21:8021/Mobile/api/Upload",file, // Send the File Blob as the POST body.
                {
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": file.type
                    },
                    params: {
                        clientFilename: file.name,
                        mimeType: file.type
                    }
                }
            )
            .toPromise();
        return({
            name: file.name,
            type: file.type,
            size: file.size,
            url: result.url,
        });
 
}
```

Comment: can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution,

The following code is working for both android and iOS:

upload.html:

```
<ion-button color="dark" (click)="selectVideo()"></ion-button>
```

upload.ts:

```
      const options: CameraOptions = {
        sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY, 
        mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.VIDEO      
      }
        this.camera.getPicture(options).then(async (videoUrl) => {
          debugger;
          this.selectvideopath=videoUrl;
          const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
          const options: FileUploadOptions = {
            fileKey: 'file',
            fileName: "<yourfilename>.mp4",
            headers: {},
            params: {}
          };
          const apiUrl = 'http://example.com/api/Upload';
          try {
              const response = await fileTransfer.upload(this.selectvideopath, apiUrl, options);
              console.log('Upload success: ' + response.responseCode);
            } catch (error) {
              console.error('Error uploading file: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
            }
          console.log(this.selectvideopath);
         }, (err) => {
          // Handle error
         });
```