# npm i com-badrit-base64 plugin is not working

Tags: ionic-native, ionic6

I am using ionic framework with capacitor. I need to convert video file to base64 string. I have added the following plugins on my android and iOS.

```
npm i com-badrit-base64
npm install @ionic-native/base64
```

I have used the following code to convert video file to base64:

```
var videobinary1=this.base64.encodeFile(retrievedFile.nativeURL).then(
                  (base64string:any) =>{
                  console.log('file base64 encoding: ' + base64string);
                });
```

For Android, We are getting the result.
But iOS, We are getting the error like below:

```
[warn] - Native: tried calling Base64.encodeFile, but the Base64 plugin is not installed.
[warn] - Install the Base64 plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add com-badrit-base64'
[log] - null
[error] - ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): plugin_not_installed
```

But We have install the **npm i com-badrit-base64** plugin on iOS also.

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not convert the video file to base64 for iOS. So I send the video file to the server through API. Find the link below:
[upload file to server using ionic framework and web api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75105158/upload-file-to-server-using-ionic-framework-and-web-api/75730281#75730281)